# ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190100", line 590

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, cursor, oracle-apex

I created a cursor which adds a missing month(which is not given in my data source) with the help of loop. My data source has all months except 10.

```
DECLARE
CURSOR CURNAME IS
select distinct year, month  from Business
UNION
select distinct the__year, the_month  from Business_2019
BEGIN
FOR REC IS CURTIME LOOP
i = REC.MONTH;
IF REC = 1 THEN
INSERT INTO DIM_TIME VALUES(YEAR, MONTH)
ELSE 
INSERT INTO DIM_TIME VALUES(YEAR, i)
i = i + 1;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Does the block of code run when running it from SQLPlus or SQL Developer and you are connected as the same user APEX is running the code as? Does your APEX user have **READ** privileges on `Business` and `Business_2019`? Does your APEX user have **INSERT** privileges on the `DIM_TIME` table?

Answer (score 0):

There are several sytax errors with the code you have shared. In the future, test the code in SQLPlus or SQL Developer or any development tool you have before running it in APEX.

This is the code with the syntax errors corrected. You will likely get a runtime error though because `IF REC = 1` will not be able to be compared properly.

```sql
DECLARE
    CURSOR CURNAME IS
        SELECT DISTINCT year, month
          FROM Business
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT the__year, the_month
          FROM Business_2019;
BEGIN
    FOR REC IN CURNAME
    LOOP
        i := REC.MONTH;

        IF REC = 1
        THEN
            INSERT INTO DIM_TIME
                 VALUES (YEAR, MONTH);
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO DIM_TIME
                 VALUES (YEAR, i);

            i := i + 1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: I GOT THE FOLLOWING ERRORS:            ORA-06550: line 11, column 9:
PLS-00201: identifier 'I' must be declared
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190100", line 590
ORA-06550: line 11, column 9:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 13, column 16:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '='
ORA-06550: line 13, column 9:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190100", line 576
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2033

Comment: As i had said in my previous comment, you should test your code in a IDE such as SQL Developer. It will make it easier to identify what is wrong with your code. Once you have functioning code, then try putting it into APEX.